# How to get the size (or) how many keys in semaphore in systemverilog

Tags: ipc, semaphore, system-verilog, verification

Is there a way to know the size of the semaphore. Like how we get the size incase of mailbox.
Is it possible to know the size of the semaphore are is it possible to write the logic to understand that

Comment: standard does not give you this possibility. I think the way around it is to create your own semaphore class derived from the built-in and keep the size in ist fields.

Comment: Thank you sir. where can I search for this standard class of semaphore in my tool. How can I check for that. I'm using Questa as tool

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in SystemVerilog to know the number of keys stored in a semaphore without acquiring them using a `get`. Even if there were such a built-in method, or extended a semaphore, the answer it would provided could never be valid after you received it.

A `semaphore` provides what is known as an *atomic test and set* capability. This means the `get` method can check the for number of keys (*test*) and immediately take them (*set*) without the possibility of another concurrent process interrupting between the testing and setting. Semaphores are typically used when there are multiple concurrent process competing for the same resource.

A `mailbox` is a messaging queue. It is typically used to synchronize two processes where one is doing the `put` and the other is doing the `get`. It makes more sense to test the size of the mailbox to know if the message was received, or if the mailbox is getting full.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you could use a mailbox instead of a semaphore and just ignore the message. Except that the number of messages waiting becomes the keys. This works as long as you only intend to `get` one key at a time.